# Overload sumOf and use both prewritten and my own simultaneously in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I have next class:

```
data class IntHolder(val x: Int) {
    operator fun plus(other: IntHolder) = IntHolder(x + other.x)
}
```

And an extension function `Iterable<T>.sumOf((T) -> IntHolder)`:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTypeInference::class)
@OverloadResolutionByLambdaReturnType
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.sumOf(f: (T) -> IntHolder) = fold(IntHolder(0)) { acc, i -> acc + f(i) }
```

How can I use both `Iterable<T>.sumOf((T) -> Int)` (which is from `kotlin.collections`) and my own `Iterable<T>.sumOf((T) -> IntHolder)` simultaneously?

The next code (all together) doesn't compile:

```
import kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalTypeInference

data class IntHolder(val x: Int) {
    operator fun plus(other: IntHolder) = IntHolder(x + other.x)
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalTypeInference::class)
@OverloadResolutionByLambdaReturnType
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.sumOf(f: (T) -> IntHolder) = fold(IntHolder(0)) { acc, i -> acc + f(i) }

fun main() {
    val range = 1..5
    val a = range.sumOf { it * 2 }  //here is an error
    val b = range.sumOf { IntHolder(it * 2) }
}
```

It says

> C:\my\kotlin\src\Test.kt:13:27
> Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but IntHolder was expected

I thought the compiler will understand which version of `sumOf` I want to use, because lambdas returning type differs from ones from `kotlin.collections`.

If it's impossible to achieve what I want, please explain the reasons, I don't get it. I was absolutely sure that it might be fixed just by one more import, but I failed at it.

Comment: Maybe it's because the standard `sumOf` doesn't have `@OverloadResolutionByLambdaReturnType` according to https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-of.html? Though I don't know why it works at all in this case.

Comment: It does, I found this annotation in `kotlin.collections.sumOf` sources and copied it into my example, but it didn't help.

Comment: Ah, just not shown then.

Answer (score 1):

Use an import alias!

```
import kotlin.collections.sumOf as classicTasteSumOf
```

and refer to it with that function name instead. (You can do alt+enter on the function name and do it automatically too)

Comment: Well, it's a simple workaround, right, but maybe it's possible without renaming? I mean, It would be nicer to use `sumOf` everywhere, without thinking of which version I really need here.

Comment: Oh, you mean you want the compiler to see you're passing lambda that returns an ``IntHolder``, so it automatically resolves to the ``IntHolder`` version of ``sumOf``? Yeah honestly I'm not sure why it doesn't - you might want to edit your question so it's more about overload resolution, and see if some of the language experts know anything. The spec is here: https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html and it explains the process of resolving them, but it's beyond me I'm afraid!

Comment: That's exaclty what I want. Probably I should create a new question instead of modifying this one because it changes current question a little. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to copy the sumof Int->Int to your code

```
import kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalTypeInference

data class IntHolder(val x: Int) {
    operator fun plus(other: IntHolder) = IntHolder(x + other.x)
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalTypeInference::class)
@OverloadResolutionByLambdaReturnType
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.sumOf(f: (T) -> IntHolder) = fold(IntHolder(0)) { acc, i -> acc + f(i) }

inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.sumOf(selector: (T) -> Int): Int {
    var sum: Int = 0.toInt()
    for (element in this) {
        sum += selector(element)
    }
    return sum
} 


fun main() {
    val range = 1..5
    val a = range.sumOf { it * 2 }  //here is an error
    val b = range.sumOf { IntHolder(it * 2) }
}
```

or to use an import alias

Comment: As you might know, there is a bunch of overloaded versions of sumOf, one for each built-in data type, and I don't really want to copy-paste them. It's good as a workaround, but not as a solution I'm looking for.